# How to use $(this).closest() in jquery

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a jquery code to animate a div when I hover an image. It works fine but the problem is that I have several images and divs with the same classes and the animation happens in all images at the same time.

I need the this script to work separately in each image/div. If I hover the first image then just the "firt div" should be animated.

watch in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chefnelone/77K8r/1/

html:

```
    <div class="main-wrapper">

<div class="rel-wrap">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/920/300" width="920" height="300" class="my-img">
    <div class="my-div">
        first div
    </div>
</div>

<div class="rel-wrap">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/920/300" width="920" height="300" class="my-img">
    <div class="my-div">
        second div
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.my-img').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.my-div').animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
    });
    $('.rel-wrap').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.my-div').delay( 1000).animate({left: '-940px'}, 1000);
    }); 
});
```

css:

```
.rel-wrap {
    position:relative;
    width:920px;
    height:300px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.my-div{
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 920px;
    height: 300px;
    left: -940px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `closest` is the right way, as it will still work if your HTML slightly changes (for example you change the order of elements or you put an intermediate wrapping element), that's why you don't use `parent()` or `next()`. Here's how you can use it :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.my-img').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).closest('.rel-wrap').find('.my-div').animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
    });
    $('.rel-wrap').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.my-div', this).delay( 1000).animate({left: '-940px'}, 1000);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: +1 yea you right, using closest is probably the best way to do this